# Set Theory - Symmetric set minus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to solve the following issue:

Assume that $A\Delta B \subseteq A \Delta C$, show that $A\cap C \subseteq B \subseteq A\cup C$.

I've tried to use the definition of the symmetric set minus: $A\Delta B = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

But it didn't get me very far.

$(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c = (A\cup B)\cap (A^c \cup B^c)$

But I'm not sure where to move on with this proof.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would do this with elements personally.

Comment: @CameronWilliams So, would you take an element from $x\in A\cap C$ and show it is also in group $B$, and likewise for $y \in B$ in $A\cup C$?

Comment: Exactly. I think you'll have more success that way.